# How would I write a statement that will loop continuously as long as an array contains a certain value in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, chess

How would I write a statement that will loop continuously as long as an array contains a certain value? I need it to continue to loop as long as an array contains a specific character, but stop looping if the array does not contain those said character values.

I kinda have this below, but I'm almost 100% sure it won't work

```
for(int PieceChecker = 0, PieceChecker < 1){

        //Code that needs to be carried out

        if (Arrays.asList(board).contains(♖)){
        PieceChecker++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the array type?

Comment: @shmosel its an array of chars

Comment: `while (new String(board).indexOf('♖') > -1) { ... }`

Comment: @shmosel for multiple conditions, i would just use && and ||, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to handle cases like these which involve just characters, by using a string than a list. Use an infinite `for` loop and break out of it once you find the absence of that character in it. You can use the `indexOf` for this purpose.

Here is the code snippet that might help you:

```
String board_string = new String(board);
for(;;) {
    if(board_string.indexOf('♖') == -1) {
        System.out.println("Breaking out of loop...");
        break;
    }
    else {
    //do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a `while` loop.  The basic construct could be

```
while (true) {
    // test situation
    if (!goodSituation()) {
        break;
    }
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: No probs Sir.. By the way, what's the `goodSituation()` function?

Comment: It is just a *stub* for some code that the OP may want top implement

Answer (score 0):

From question it is not clear that you want to loop around simple char array OR the list of character array. 
Here I came up with something which might help.

```
private static char[] myCharArray = new char[] { '\u00A9', '\u00AE', '\u00DD', 'A', 'B' };
private static Logger _log = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getCanonicalName());


public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 1. Using character array directly
    for (int i = 0; i < myCharArray.length; i++) {
        while (myCharArray[i] == '\u00A9') {
            _log.info("Inside char array as this condition holds true");
        }
    }

    // 2. List of char arrays.
    List<char[]> list = Arrays.asList(myCharArray);
    for (char[] cs : list) {
        for (char c : cs) {
            while(c =='A'){
                _log.info("Inside charToList array as this condition holds true");  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while (Arrays.asList(board).contains("♖")) {
    //do something
}
```

**Edit** based on @shmosel's comment:-

For primitive arrays like `int[]`, you can use something like this in the `while` condition:-

```
IntStream.of(a).anyMatch(x -> x == 2)
```

For a primitive `char` array, you can use this condition:-

```
new String(cArr).indexOf('♖') > -1
```

Comment: @shmosel why not?

Comment: @shmosel that part is taken from OP's code, I am just showing the use of `while` loop

Comment: OP's code is obviously wrong. It doesn't even have quotes.

Comment: @shmosel my code is probably wrong somewhere , i'm just starting CS and am absolutely awful

Comment: Still won't work for a `char` array. And `"♖"` is not a char.

Comment: the other downvoter - I had added the char array check, just didn't comment about it